# Rng library vs. java.util.Random API

Tags: scala, random, monads

In Scala I can use either `java.util.Random` or `Rng` [library](https://github.com/NICTA/rng) (or any other monadic API). `Rng` (as other monadic approaches) provides a pure solution without side-effects but probably has performance overhead. If we need to calculate a random value we build a *computation* first and run it later.

I guess it is *easier* (and hence more practical) to use `java.util.Random` in simple cases (e.g. shuffle a deck, roll a dice, pick a random sample from a set). Now I wonder when one should use `Rng` (or other monadic approaches).

What is the *simplest* example of a random computation where `Rng` shines ?

Comment: It's not about concision so much as correctness. Suppose I need to be able to replicate runs of some simulation that uses random numbers. It's possible to do this with `Random`, but it can get tricky, especially in the face of concurrency, etc. You're definitely not going to get any help from the type system. `Rng` has some syntactic overhead but it's much easier to reason about in complicated situations.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thank you.The run replication is a good example (while I think I can do it with the Java API too).

Comment: @TravisBrown I guess `Rng` has some _performance_ overhead.

Comment: Right, it does, although there are plenty of cases where the additional guarantees are worth paying the performance tax.

Comment: @TravisBrown - Could you expand on that claim a little?  _What_ guarantee are you making that is not more easily and efficiently made using some other scheme?  "I need to replicate runs using concurrency" either means "I need each thread to have its own RNG" which isn't aided by explicitly passing the RNG in and getting it back out, or it means "Actually, I want to block all my threads in favor of an absolute order dictated by my RNG" which is a weird thing to want but is also trivially handled by the RNG itself without contaminating all your method signatures.

Comment: @RexKerr `java.util.Random` uses `AtomicLong` to store the seed. I guess the "atomicity" adds some overhead even if there is no concurrent access to the seed. So we pay for what we don't use.

Comment: @Michael - You pay less, and you can always use a thread-unsafe mutable random number library (e.g. in Spire, for Scala).  And you avoid accidentally branching your random number stream into a tree.

Comment: @RexKerr In order to avoid the accidental branching one can probably make a wrapper over `Rng`.

Comment: @RexKerr Do you mean that the "atomicity" overhead is less than the  performance overhead of `Rng` ?

Comment: @Michael - Unless there's a lot of contention, yes, the atomicity overhead is less.  If there is a lot of contention, neither approach is ideal: atomicity is slow but correct, while immutability if fast is wrong (because of duplicate random number streams in the different branches).

Comment: @RexKerr What's wrong with branching of random number streams ?

Comment: @Michael - There are correlations between the output of one stream and another (e.g. they may be exactly identical).  For example, suppose you are using this to generate random molecule motions.  It wouldn't work so well if all molecules made the exact same sequence of "random" motions!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't about the computation; it's about the packaging.

The linked library provides a number of examples of how you would use the `Rng` monadic interface to produce nicely packaged code. It is compact, with an expressive concision typical of Scala programs.

Comment: Could you point me out to such an Rng example, which would be hard to implement nicely with `java.util.Random` ?

Comment: It's not **hard** to implement in Java; it just takes a bunch more symbols. With the introduction of lambdas in Java 8, basic functional composition becomes easier, but you can still express it more concisely in Scala.

Comment: Ok. I see. So the advantage of `Rng` is conciseness. Could you point me out to an `Rng` example, which would be significantly less concise if it were implemented with `java.util.Random` instead of `Rng` ?

Comment: @BobDalgleish - Your comment is not helpful because it refers to an external source of substantial size without highlighting where the answer to the question is.  For example, on the front-page doc is says you can easily monadically create a generator for Person.  Yay!  Except the mutable version is shorter: `def randomPerson(r: Rng) = Person(r.string, r.int)`.  It seems _less_ compact, not more.  Any of the generators could be written in mutable context.  As a matter of principle it is interesting to see that the syntactic penalty can be smallish, but it still seems a penalty.